# Caching OpenLDAP credentials for offline use on laptops

Tags: ubuntu, cache, openldap, laptop

Our clients (Ubuntu 14.04) can login with there LDAP login.
As soon as they have no network they cannot login with LDAP.

Is there a way to cache those passwords and usernames,
so that the laptops can work if they don't have an LDAP connection?

Comment: Cached credentials in general are a somewhat bad idea, how many users per laptop and how often do they need to work offline? Depending on what your needs are there may be a better solution

Comment: sssd has support for cached credentials https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/SSSD-Introduction.html

Answer (score 7):

Debian and Ubuntu provide the libpam-ccreds package, that caches network login credentials.  From the package description:

> This package provides the means for Linux workstations to locally 
>   authenticate using an enterprise identity when the network is
>   unavailable.  Used in conjunction with the nss_updatedb utility, it
>   provides a mechanism for  disconnected use of network directories.
>   They are designed to work with  libpam-ldap and libnss-ldap.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [sssd daemon](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Enterprise/Authentication/sssd).

It has a cache credentials feature in the config file:

```
cache_credentials = true
```

After login, the user's credentials are cached so that they can log in again without access to the LDAP server.

Comment: Hi, i tried to setup the ssshd deamon: this is given the following errror: (Thu Feb  5 11:33:27 2015) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [sdap_connect_done] (0x0080): START TLS result: Protocol error(2), unsupported extended operation
(Thu Feb  5 11:33:27 2015) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [sdap_connect_done] (0x0080): ldap_install_tls failed: [Connect error] [A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.]     My OpenLDAP is created without a certificate is this needed?

Comment: i had always correct certificate. but - try to use ldap_tls_reqcert = never

Answer (score 1):

My OpenLDAP was a basic setup without SSL or TLS I think this was the problem.

I downloaded an appliance for OpenLDAP via http://www.turnkeylinux.org/openldap and setup it within minutes. This appliance has SSL and TLS based on a self signed certificate.

Now with the TLS configured and the self signed cert, the option ldap_tls_reqcert = never must be used in the sssd.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

For caching credentials on Linux there are mainly used the two programs **sssd** and **ccreds** as mentioned in the other answers. I tried `sssd` but it installed a big amount of additional shared libraries and dependent packages I do not need. So I decided to use the lightweight `ccreds`. But I wasn't able to find much detailed instructions how to use it, mostly only general hints to use this program. So I will elaborate the answer of *@AndrewSchulman* to share with the community how I managed it. I use a Debian Buster installation and have a working [online Kerberos/OpenLDAP authentication/authorization system](https://serverfault.com/a/993929/458473). I get a valid Kerberos ticket with `kinit` and on logon.

First install the needed programs:

```
~$ sudo apt install libnss-db nss-updatedb libpam-ccreds
```

With `sudo pam-auth-update` I set the options

```
[*] Ccreds credential caching - password saving
[*] Ccreds credential caching - password checking
```

In `/etc/nsswitch.conf` I have to modify to:

```
passwd:         files ldap [NOTFOUND=return] db
group:          files ldap [NOTFOUND=return] db
```

Now I can check if the caching databases are created:

```
~$ sudo nss_updatedb ldap
passwd... done.
group... done.
~$ ls -l /var/lib/misc/*.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8192 Feb 26 12:46 /var/lib/misc/group.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8192 Feb 26 12:46 /var/lib/misc/passwd.db

~$ su -l ingo
ingo: ~$ logout
~$ ls -l /var/cache/.security.db
-rw------- 1 root ingo 8192 Feb 26 12:55 /var/cache/.security.db

~$ sudo cc_dump
Credential Type  User             Service  Cached Credentials
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Salted SHA1      ingo             any     c2da4cd14bd00bd7ecd72ab15e565e9149b46fd5
```

No, that isn't my SHA1 credential ;-) Because I use the clear text password on the command line I will not cache it in the bash history.

```
~$ history -a
~$ sudo cc_test -validate any ingo <password>
pam_cc_validate_credentials: Success
~$ history -c
~$ history -r
```

You should find users and groups that are only defined on the LDAP directory and you should be able to login, even if you are offline:

```
~$ sudo ip link set eth0 down
~$ getent passwd|group
~$ su -l ingo
ingo: ~$ logout
~$ sudo ip link set if up
```

I have seen some delays after installing but they disappear after a reboot.

---

**References:**
[ubuntu - PamCcredsHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PamCcredsHowto)