# NSS query against OpenLDAP server using GSSAPI with proxy authorization

Tags: pam-ldap, nss, gssapi, debian-buster, proxy-authentication

SASL/GSSAPI needs Kerberos authentication against the LDAP server with proxy authorization if using [LDAP authentication with nss-pam-ldapd](https://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/setup) on a Debian Buster operating system. I try to configure this on my Raspberry Pis to have single sign on but cannot get it to work.

I have my ldap server configured with [How to setup SASL Proxy Authorization with an OpenLDAP server on Debian](https://serverfault.com/a/993554/458473). I named the proxy user **proxyuser** so its distinguished name is `uid=proxyuser,ou=people,ou=home,dc=hoeft-online,dc=de`.

According to [LDAP authentication with nss-pam-ldapd](https://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/setup) on a Debian system I have to install packages `libnss-ldapd` and `libpam-ldapd` in addition to the GSSAPI plugin `libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit`. But I will use `libpam-krb5` instead of `libpam-ldapd`:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit libnss-ldapd ldap-utils
```

On installation it was presented a configuration dialog that settings are stored in `/etc/nslcd.conf` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. I have to configure again with

```
rpi ~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure nslcd
rpi ~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure libnss-ldapd
```

My settings given from the dialogs are:

```
rpi ~$ sudo cat /etc/nslcd.conf
# /etc/nslcd.conf
# nslcd configuration file. See nslcd.conf(5)
# for details.

# The user and group nslcd should run as.
uid nslcd
gid nslcd

# The location at which the LDAP server(s) should be reachable.
uri ldap://kdc-master.home.hoeft-online.de

# The search base that will be used for all queries.
base ou=home,dc=hoeft-online,dc=de

# The LDAP protocol version to use.
#ldap_version 3

# The DN to bind with for normal lookups.
#binddn cn=annonymous,dc=example,dc=net
#bindpw secret

# The DN used for password modifications by root.
#rootpwmoddn cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com

# SSL options
#ssl off
#tls_reqcert never
tls_cacertfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# The search scope.
#scope sub

sasl_mech GSSAPI
krb5_ccname /var/run/nslcd/nslcd.tkt
sasl_authzid dn:uid=proxyuser,ou=people,ou=home,dc=hoeft-online,dc=de
```

```
~$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files ldap
group:          files ldap
shadow:         files ldap
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Now with `getent passwd` I expect to get the credentials of **ingo** from the LDAP server. It isn't stored in local `/etc/passwd`. But I only get the local entries from `/etc/passwd`. In the logs of the LDAP server I can see that there is no attempt to BIND to **proxyuser**. What I'm missing here?
**Why `getent` does not get credentials from the LDAP server?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The short answer

Be sure you have a valid `/etc/krb5.keytab` with your `host/*` principal, e.g. doing:

```
rpi ~$ sudo kadmin -p user/admin
kadmin:  addprinc -policy host -randkey host/<hostname>.home.hoeft-online.de
kadmin:  ktadd -k /etc/krb5.keytab host/<hostname>.home.hoeft-online.de
kadmin:  q
```

Disable caching daemon `nscd` if available with `sudo systemctl disable --now nscd.service`. Don't confuse it with `nslcd`. Then check [Proxy Authorization](https://serverfault.com/q/993553/458473):

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit ldap-utils
rpi ~$ kinit -p ingo
rpi ~$ ldapwhoami -Y GSSAPI -H ldap://kdc-master.home.hoeft-online.de -D "uid=proxyuser,ou=people,ou=home,dc=hoeft-online,dc=de"
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: ingo@HOME.HOEFT-ONLINE.DE
SASL SSF: 256
SASL data security layer installed.
dn:uid=ingo,ou=people,ou=home,dc=hoeft-online,dc=de
```

Then install:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install libnss-ldapd kstart
```

Just accept the default settings in the installation dialog. We overwrite them with these configuration files. Use them with your settings:
nslcd.conf

```
~$ sudo cat /etc/nslcd.conf
# /etc/nslcd.conf
# nslcd configuration file. See nslcd.conf(5)
# for details.

# The user and group nslcd should run as.
uid nslcd
gid nslcd

# Logging options, default is info
#log syslog debug

# The location at which the LDAP server(s) should be reachable.
uri ldap://kdc-master.home.hoeft-online.de

# The search base that will be used for all queries.
base ou=home,dc=hoeft-online,dc=de

# The DN to bind with for normal lookups.
binddn uid=proxyuser,ou=people,ou=home,dc=hoeft-online,dc=de

# Timing/reconnect options
# You may optimize this for your environment
#bind_timelimit 10
timelimit 30
idle_timelimit 3600
reconnect_sleeptime 2
#reconnect_retrytime 10

# SSL options
#ssl off
#tls_reqcert never
tls_cacertfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# SASL options
sasl_mech GSSAPI
krb5_ccname /var/run/nslcd/nslcd.tkt

# Other options
nss_initgroups_ignoreusers ALLLOCAL
```

nsswitch.conf

```
~$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd:         files ldap
group:          files ldap
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Restart the service and check. Be sure *ingo* has no local unix account in `/etc/passwd`.

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl restart nslcd.service
rpi ~$ getent passwd | grep ingo
```

setup PAM login with Kerberos authentication:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install libpam-krb5
rpi ~$ sudo pam-auth-update
# select what you need
[*] Kerberos authentication
[*] Unix authentication
[*] Create home directory on login

# check
rpi ~$ kdestroy
rpi ~$ su -l ingo
password:
ingo@rpi ~$ klist
ingo@rpi ~$ logout
rpi ~$
```

Install nscd caching daemon (or enable it if already available):

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install nscd
```

That's it.

### Some more details

It took me several days to examine what's wrong with the setup. For troubleshooting you can increase logging to debug output, on the LDAP server to `olcLogLevel: any`:

```
slapd ~$ echo 'dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcLogLevel
olcLogLevel: any' > /tmp/in.ldif

slapd ~$ sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /tmp/in.ldif
```

On the client device just uncomment the debug log line in `/etc/nslcd.conf`.

Restart the service and disable caching daemon `nscd` (don't mix up with `nslcd`) because `nscd` may confuse testing:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl restart nslcd.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl disable --now nscd.service
```

Don't forget to revert debug logging and enable **nscd** when finished. Executing `getent passwd` you will see in the client log that it not even starts with `GSSAPI client step 1`, nothing. I realized that the nslcd.service does not get any credentials in `/var/run/nslcd/nslcd.tkt` for its authentication. Poking around I found in `/etc/default/nslcd` that there has to start `/usr/bin/k5start` but that isn't installed and nowhere documented. So just install it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install kstart
```

Now the log shows that GSSAPI starts with step 1 but then aborts.

Most confusing is the presented setup dialog on installing `libnss-ldapd`. It's asking for entries that are wrong for my setup with GSSAPI in particular the distinguished name for the proxy user (sasl_authzid). This is not usable. Instead you have to use the normal **binddn**. Just accept the default settings in the dialog setup and afterwards use the config files from the short answer.

I use **systemd-networkd** together with **systemd-resolved**. With the systemd resolver I got an annoying delay of 60 seconds on login that wasn't acceptable. The `journal -b` shows me that querying the ldap server for group membership timed out after 60 seconds:

```
Feb 26 01:25:45 titan systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Feb 26 01:25:45 titan systemd[1]: Starting LSB: LDAP connection daemon...
Feb 26 01:25:45 titan nslcd[441]: Starting Keep alive Kerberos ticket: k5start.
Feb 26 01:25:45 titan nslcd[455]: version 0.9.10 starting
Feb 26 01:25:45 titan nslcd[455]: accepting connections
Feb 26 01:25:45 titan nslcd[441]: Starting LDAP connection daemon: nslcd.
Feb 26 01:25:45 titan systemd[1]: Started LSB: LDAP connection daemon.
Feb 26 01:25:46 titan login[435]: pam_krb5(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=local uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=
Feb 26 01:25:46 titan login[435]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user local by LOGIN(uid=0)
Feb 26 01:25:46 titan systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 65533.
Feb 26 01:25:46 titan systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/65533...
Feb 26 01:25:46 titan systemd-logind[428]: New session 1 of user local.
Feb 26 01:25:46 titan systemd[1]: Started User Runtime Directory /run/user/65533.
Feb 26 01:25:46 titan systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 65533...

Feb 26 01:26:11 titan login[435]: pam_systemd(login:session): Failed to create session: Connection timed out
Feb 26 01:26:46 titan dbus-daemon[426]: [system] Connection has not authenticated soon enough, closing it (auth_timeout=30000ms, elapsed: 60060ms)
Feb 26 01:26:46 titan nslcd[455]: [8b4567] <group/member="local"> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://kdc-master.home.hoeft-online.de: Can't contact LDAP server: Invalid argument
Feb 26 01:26:46 titan nslcd[455]: [8b4567] <group/member="local"> no available LDAP server found: Can't contact LDAP server: Invalid argument

Feb 26 01:26:46 titan nslcd[455]: GSSAPI client step 1
Feb 26 01:26:46 titan systemd[468]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user local by (uid=0)
Feb 26 01:26:46 titan nslcd[455]: [3c9869] <group/member="local"> connected to LDAP server ldap://kdc-master.home.hoeft-online.de
Feb 26 01:26:46 titan systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 65533.
Feb 26 01:26:46 titan systemd[1]: Started Session 1 of user local.
```

After days of error hunting I found that option `nss_initgroups_ignoreusers ALLLOCAL` in `/etc/nslcd.conf` fixed this error. This  option  prevents  group  membership lookups through LDAP of non-LDAP users. It means that local registered users like system accounts will not have a lookup to the LDAP server.