# Single sign on using SSSD against OpenLDAP server with Kerberos SASL/GSSAPI

Tags: openldap, sssd, mitkerberos, debian-buster, gssapi

Authentication against Kerberos and authorization against an LDAP directory is working for me. Now I'm looking for the client setup on Debian Buster using **sssd**.

I started with [LDAP authentication with nss-pam-ldapd](https://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/setup) using [SASL Proxy Authorization on an OpenLDAP server](https://serverfault.com/a/993554/458473) and [Caching OpenLDAP credentials with **ccreds**](https://serverfault.com/a/1004660/458473). But because I consistent use **systemd** and its environment, that traditional setup does not fit very well to it and I run into some problems with **systemd-resolved** together with **nsswitch** and/or **pam** as shown in [section "Some more details" about NSS query against OpenLDAP server](https://serverfault.com/a/993929/458473).

Because of this I had a look at **sssd** and saw that it can do it all in one and that it is based on **systemd** and also uses **dbus** interprocess communication. So I decided to use it instead. But on Debian the recommended package **sssd** installs all possible services, e.g. for active directory and other things I do not need. I want to have my clients as lean as possible without unused software, so my question is:

What Debian packages only I have to install to get a single sign on using **sssd** against OpenLDAP server with Kerberos SASL/GSSAPI and how to configure it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Abstract

After some tries and error I found that I need one package for gssapi and four packages for sssd. I want to have general configuration centralized so I use a local private dns server for name-, servername- and servicename-resolution. So first I check this on the client. If you don't have it on a DNS server you can define it all local on every client. I have commented it. To avoid installation of unneeded additional packages I always use option `--no-install-recommends` for Debian **apt**.

### Prepare Kerberos client

First ensure that you have a valid `/etc/krb5.keytab` with `sudo klist -ke`. If not available then create one:

```
rpi ~$ sudo kadmin -p user/admin
kadmin:  addprinc -policy host -randkey host/<hostname>.example.com
kadmin:  ktadd host/<hostname>.example.com
kadmin:  q
```

After installing a Graphical User Interface like GNOME, or Xfce, I run into problems with name resolution. **sssd** wasn't able to resolve the DNS domain `example.com` with my extended DNS name resolution, so it does not find the Kerberos- and LDAP-server and login fails with error message `Authentication failure`. This may work sometimes because of cached login data but with invalid kerberos ticket data `1970-01-01` shown with `klist`. According to [Debian hostname resolution](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_hostname_resolution) you should have an entry in `/etc/hosts` like this:

```
127.0.1.1    <hostname>.example.com    <hostname>
```

If you have the **nscd** cache running for name service then deinstall it. We must not use it because **sssd** will do the same.

```
~$ sudo systemctl disable --now nscd.service
~$ sudo apt purge nscd
~$ sudo apt-mark hold nscd
```

Install SASL/GSSAPI modules and helpers we need for authentication against Kerberos and tests:

```
~$ sudo apt --no-install-recommends install libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit dnsutils ldap-utils

# check DNS resolution; must resolve full qualified dns names
~$ dig +noall +answer $(hostname -f)
~$ dig +noall +answer -x $(hostname -I)

# Check Kerberos server and LDAP server
~$ dig +noall +answer ldap-primary.example.com
~$ dig +noall +answer kdc-master.example.com

# Query for kerberos service (response: kdc10-1.example.com on port 88)
~$ dig +noall +answer SRV _kerberos._udp.example.com
_kerberos._udp.example.com 38400 IN SRV   0 0 88 kdc10-1.example.com.
# Query for ldap service (response: kdc10-1.example.com on port 389)
~$ dig +noall +answer SRV _ldap._tcp.example.com
_ldap._tcp.example.com. 38400 IN SRV   0 0 389 kdc10-1.example.com.

# Check if the sssd.service can access the LDAP-server. It uses this principal
~$ sudo kinit -k host/<hostname>.example.com
~$ sudo ldapsearch -Y GSSAPI -LLL -H ldap://ldap-primary.example.com -b "ou=home,dc=example,dc=com" "(cn=ingo)" uid cn
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: host/<hostname>.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
SASL SSF: 256
SASL data security layer installed.
dn: cn=ingo,ou=group,ou=home,dc=example,dc=com
cn: ingo

dn: uid=ingo,ou=people,ou=home,dc=example,dc=com
uid: ingo
cn: Ingo
```

## Install sssd

---

We need just four packages to provide all needed services for ldap, krb5, name service and pam:

```
~$ sudo apt --no-install-recommends install sssd-ldap sssd-krb5 libnss-sss libpam-sss
```

The only what's left over is to configure `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`. I use this one:

```
~$ sudo cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
[sssd]
# debug log files in /var/log/sssd/
#debug_level = 7
config_file_version = 2
domains = HOME
# don't set services on Debian Bullseye. It's managed there
# by sssd-nss.socket and sssd-pam-priv.socket
services = nss, pam

[nss]
#debug_level = 7

[pam]
#debug_level = 7

[domain/HOME]
#debug_level = 7
# Set enumerate only for debugging, never for production!
#enumerate = TRUE

id_provider = ldap
# If you haven't a SRV record in DNS for the server then set it here
#ldap_uri = ldap://ldap-primary.example.com
# SRV record for backup server isn't supported. We have to set it always.
ldap_backup_uri = ldap://ldap-secondary.example.com
ldap_search_base = ou=home,dc=example,dc=com
ldap_sasl_mech = gssapi

auth_provider = krb5
chpass_provider = krb5
# Maybe I want to use the .k5login file in the home directory of the user
access_provider = krb5

# If you haven't a SRV record in DNS for the server then set it here
#krb5_server = kdc-master.example.com
# SRV record for backup server isn't supported. We have to set it always.
krb5_backup_server = kdc-replica.example.com
# If the authid isn't the first entry in /etc/krb5.keytab then set it here
#ldap_sasl_authid = host/<hostname>.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
# krb5_realm must always be set here. There is no look at `/etc/krb5.conf`
krb5_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
#krb5_renewable_lifetime = 3d
krb5_renew_interval = 1h

# I don't use this
sudo_provider = none
autofs_provider = none

cache_credentials = TRUE
```

Don't forget to protect sssd.conf, otherwise sssd will not start:

```
~$ sudo chmod 600 /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
~$ sudo systemctl restart sssd.service
```

Check if the operating system gets the account information from the ldap directory. Be sure the queried user account is only in the ldap directory, not in local files. The source of the query is indicated by the character behind the user id.

```
:x:   from local files (/etc/passwd and /etc/group)
:*:   from the ldap directory
```

Be sure you get **`:*:`**.

```
~$ getent passwd ingo
ingo:*:1000:1000:Ingo:/home/ingo:/bin/bash
~$ getent group ingo
ingo:*:1000:
```

Set pam authentication for login:

```
~$ sudo pam-auth-update
[*] Unix authentication
[*] SSS authentication
[*] Register user sessions in the systemd control group hierarchy
[*] Create home directory on login
```

and check login with a new user:

```
~$ ~$ su -l ingo
Password:
Creating directory '/home/ingo'.
ingo:~$ klist
ingo:~$ logout
~$
```

For testing settings in sssd.conf you have to know that sssd is caching many data so changes will not immediately have an effect. This is very confusing. So I deleted the files in `/var/lib/sss/db/` with the cached information after a modification of sssd.conf. I used this one-liner as root:

```
~# systemctl stop sssd.service && rm /var/lib/sss/db/* && systemctl start sssd.service
```

Comment: To invalidate thte cache of sssd one could also use: `sss_cache -E`.  This will invalidate all cached entries acccording to `man sss_cache`. In Debian one needs to install sssd-tools to get sss_cache.

Comment: @mrossi I didn't know `sss_cache` before. Thanks for updating me. I will have a look at it.